# awk script to identify incorrect sequence of words

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file as shown below:

```
FHEAD01
THEAD02
TCUST03
TITEM04
TITEM05
IDISC06
TTEND07
TTAIL08
THEAD09
TCUST10
IDISC11....
TITEM12
TTEND13
TTAIL14
THEAD15
TITEM16
IDISC17
TTEND18
TTAIL19
THEAD20
IDISC21.....
TITEM22
TTEND23
TTAIL24
THEAD25
TITEM26
IDISC27
IDISC28
TITEM29
TTEND30
TTAIL31
FTAIL32
```

I want to identify the following sequence and print records:

```
1) THEAD,TCUST,IDISC,*
2) THEAD,IDISC,*
```

Expected Output
Following records should be printed

```
THEAD09
TCUST10
IDISC11
THEAD20
IDISC21
```

I tried the following code, but it is not giving results:

```
awk '/THEAD/; /TCUST/ ; /IDISC/ ' test1.dat
```

Comment: What sequence? What records should be printed? Please [edit] your question and clarify your requirements. At least add your desired output sow e can understand what you need.

Comment: Also, from what I've gathered so far, why not use `egrep`?

Comment: edited the question and added expected output

Comment: So you want to print all lines starting with `THEAD` if i) the next line starts with `TCUST` and ii) the line after that starts with `IDISC`. If all three conditions are met, you want to print all three lines. Then, you also want all lines starting with `THEAD` where the next line starts with `IDISC` but only print two lines. Is that more or less correct?

Comment: @terdon.. Yes exactly this is my requirement.

Comment: OK, why awk then? It's possible in awk but there are better tools.

Comment: @terdon - Not sure about other tools

Comment: `grep -ozP 'THEAD[0-9][0-9]\n(TCUST[0-9][0-9]\n)?IDISC[0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: @Costas. Giving error `grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined` If i try with egrep then getting error  `egrep: conflicting matchers specified`

Comment: @Amit Do you have GNU grep or pgrep ? Or try to substitute -P by -E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    /THEAD/{
        p=$0                 #store line with `THEAD`
        getline              #read next line from file
        if(/TCUST/){         #if there is `TCUST` in it
            p=p ORS $0       #add it to `p` vaiable
            getline          #and get next line from file
            }
        if(/IDISC/)          #if there is `IDISC` in line
            print p ORS $0   #print `p` variable altogether with line
    }
    ' test1.dat
```